# Laravel-auth-timeout - event and listener

Tags: laravel, events, listener

I am new to Laravel, and have installed github.com/juliomotol/laravel-auth-timeout into my application.

Everything works fine until I try to implement a listener class for the package installed event.  I am trying to have the user redirected to the login page, with an informative banner showing they have been logged out due to inactivity, as soon as as laravel-auth-timeout triggers its event.  But everything I have tried just leaves the page, last viewed, showing until the user tries to perform a new action and then they are redirected.

Could someone please help me to make the redirection automatic once laravel-auth-timeout triggers its event.

Many thanks.

In AuthTimeoutMiddleware.php

```
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    // When there are no user's logged in, just let them pass through
    if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
        return $next($request);
    }

    // First we'll initialize a session when none has been set yet.
    $this->authTimeout->init();

    // Then we'll check if the user have timed out.
    if (!$this->authTimeout->check($guard)) {
        throw new AuthenticationException('Timed out.', [$guard], $this->redirectTo($request, $guard));
    }

    // If the user is not yet timed out, we'll reset the timeout session
    // and proceed with the pipeline.
    $this->authTimeout->reset();

    return $next($request);
}

/**
 * Get the path the user should be redirected to when they timed out.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  mixed    $guard
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function redirectTo($request, $guard)
{
    return route('auth.timed-login');
}
```

In AuthTimeout.php

```
    /**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function check($guard = null)
{
    // When there are no user's logged in, we'll return false.
    if ($this->auth->guard($guard)->guest()) {
        return false;
    }

    $lastActiveAt = Carbon::parse($this->session->get($this->session_name));
    $timeoutAt = $lastActiveAt->addMinutes(config('auth-timeout.timeout'));

    // Now lets check if they are still within the timeout threshold.
    if ($timeoutAt->greaterThan(Carbon::now())) {
        return true;
    }

    // At this point we know that they have timed out so we'll log them
    // out, dispatch an event, invalidate the session we've set, and return
    // false.
    $user = $this->auth->guard($guard)->user();

    $this->auth->guard($guard)->logout();
    $this->event->dispatch(new AuthTimeoutEvent($user, $guard));
    $this->session->forget($this->session_name);

    return false;
}
```

In the listener I have written

```
/**
 * Handle the event.
 *
 * @param  AuthTimeoutEvent  $event
 * @return void
 */
public function handle(AuthTimeoutEvent $event)
{
    $event->user;   // The user that timed out.
    $event->guard;  // The authentication guard.

    return redirect(route('auth.timed-login'));
}
```

And lastly in EventServiceProvider.php

```
    /**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    Registered::class => [
        SendEmailVerificationNotification::class,
    ],
    \JulioMotol\AuthTimeout\Events\AuthTimeoutEvent::class => [
        AutoTimedOutListener::class,
    ]
```

Comment: UPDATE:
I have completely abandoned laravel-auth-timeout, and have instead elected to use javascript to check for inactivity over a set time period, log the user out and redirect to an informational page.